# Interconnecting CiviCRM/Drupal and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal

We are planning to set up CiviCRM/Drupal) for a client that already has a WordPress Website. (we only use Drupal for CiviCRM).

We want to interconnect CiviCRM and WordPress so that the registered members on CiviCRM can access to private documents on WordPress without logging in (everything else on the website is public and we don't want to have the document management system within CiviCRM or Drupal).

Has anyone already done this?

We think about using a CAS server because the plug-ins already exist for Drupal and WordPress or Zapier? What would you recommend?

thanks

Guillaume

Comment: “Access to private documents without logging in” -> that’s a bit of a paradox I think. I highly recommend you have your Drupal/CiviCRM secure.yourorg.org instance look after everything that needs to be kept secure - including the use of Drupal’s private files set up as well as CiviMember Role-Sync module and an Access Permissions module (node and/or field level). And use your Wordpress site as a front-facing/brochure site yourorg.org

Comment: Why not just use the CiviCRM WordPress plugin?

Comment: We are scoping something similar for a couple of different situations. So for you is it enough for WP to just 'know' that the civi contact meets the criteria (eg 'is member'). Do your contacts get a Drupal user? Do they already have a WP user? Are you users always going to the WP site from a link on the drupal site?

Comment: @petednz: i think, it would be enough for WordPress to just "know" that this contacts the criteria. I don't think they would need and get a Drupal user (except if necessary). The wordpress site is also in development stage and I may be will they get a WP user. And they won't access from the Drupal site that we use for membership. That's why we thought about a CAS server. We still have time to think about this and anticipate.

Comment: The scenario we are scoping is a WP that used to 'check' with another CRM if the person was a Member (which sounds v similar to yours), and we have just moved them to having Drupal+Civi as well as keeping their WP site. So the WP site will need to 'check' when someone logs in to it if they are a Member in civi or not so they get 'member only' info and member pricing

Comment: this sounds pretty similar to my need. How have you managed to do this? Are there some existing plug-ins or did you develop yours?